# Running multiple root\no context web apps on single host

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a host with a single web app and at the moment I am accessing it via www.hostnameA.com/ as the web app is deployed to tomcat/webapps as the tomcat ROOT web app.

Now I need to add another web app to my host and I also want this one to have no context either but will access it via another hostname www.hostnameB.com/ but I can only deploy one ROOT tomcat web app.

I should have added that I am using apache as well and my virtual host looks like:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.hostnameA.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

   <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
   </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/   
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried renaming the war file to webAppA and then appending that to the proxypass but it gave me a 400 error and kept appending /webAppA to the URL:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/webAppA
```

Is there a solution to this? I dont really want to run multiple instances of tomcat on different ports just for this, is there another option?

Comment: You might consider introducing an Apache web server, which intercepts all requests and distributes them among your webapps - if you don't mind one more server instance running.

Comment: I do have apache running as well actually and am using virtual hosts, I just didnt think it was possible to redirect using the proxy pass and append the web name in the virtual host?

Comment: Are you using [mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) for request forwarding? I think it provides what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes I thought I was but maybe I need to use the AJP: before my url to stop the url from changing?

Comment: Well I tried following what was in the documentation and it always results in a 302 first, then a new request from my browser is triggered for www.hostnameA.com/webappA and thats not what I want, I always the access to be as if there were no context.

Comment: @f_puras if you move your answer to a proper answer I will choose it as removing the proxy pass reverse (docs say its normally not needed) and then adding a forward slash at the end of my virtual host and it works including the urls in my tomcat app.

Comment: I'd be glad to! Yet I think you will need the `ProxyPassReverse` so that all links in the resulting html be converted. I will include it in my answer, but please be gracious, because it is some time since I last configured this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed above, most straightforward solution would be to use Apache's [mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html), allowing proxying and AJP forwarding at the same time. Configuration should look something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.hostnameA.com
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/webAppA/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.hostnameA.com/webAppA 
    [...]
```

...and same with *B* for www.hostnameB.com.

Comment: This is exactly what I did but I had to add a / to the end of the proxypass ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/webAppA/ once I did that it worked ok, Thanks for the help.